# Is it possible to connect iOS (11.4) and Android (10+) via L2CAP

Tags: android, ios, l2cap

Is it possible to connect iOS (11.4) and Android (10+) via L2CAP ?

I know that via BLE it works, question is for the L2cap cross capability ios/android - anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Both support L2CAP CoC over BLE so yes, it is possible.